# Multiple shell script workers

Tags: bash, shell

**We'd like to interpret tons of coordinates and do something with them using multiple workers.
What we got:**

**coords.txt**

```
100, 100, 100
244, 433, 233
553, 212, 432
776, 332, 223
...
8887887, 5545554, 2243234
```

**worker.sh**

```
coord_reader='^([0-9]+), ([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)$'
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ $line =~ $coord_reader ]]; then

        x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        y=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        z=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        echo "x is $x, y is $y, z is $z"
fi

done < "$1"
```

To execute **worker.sh** we call `bash worker.sh coords.txt`

Bc we have an amount of millions of coordinates it's needed to split the **coords.txt** and create multiple workers doing the same task, like `coordsaa, coordsab, coordsac` each 1 worker.

So we split `coords.txt` using `split`.

```
split -l 1000 coords.txt coords
```

But, how to assign one file per worker?

*I am new to stackoverflow, feel free to comment so I can improve my asking skills.*

Comment: Just loop through the filenames, passing the filename as a command-line parameter to each worker.

Comment: I do not know each exact filename. So, how to get this done?

Comment: Thx, but the `echo` command is for demonstration only :)

Comment: Take a look at [GNU parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnu-parallel/info).

Comment: Is bash the right tool for this task? Have you considered more suitable tools, e.g. - Python or Perl?

Comment: I do not know much about Python and Perl scripting, that's the problem ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run workers from bash to treat a lot of files:

**Files architecture:**

```
files/ runner.sh worker.sh
```

`files/` : it is a folder with a lot a files (for example 1000)
`runner.sh`: launch a lot a worker
`worker.sh file`: task to treat a file

For example:

**worker.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 5
echo $1
```

To run all files in `files/` one per worker do:

**runner.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n_processes=$(find files/ -type f | wc -l)
echo "spawning  ${n_processes}"

for file in $(find . -type f); then
    bash worker.sh "${file}" &
done

wait
```

> **/!\ 1000 processes is a lot !!**

It is better to create a "pool of processes" (here it guarantees only a number maximum of process running at the same time, an old child process is not reused for a new task but died when its task is done or failed) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n_processes=8
echo "max of processes:  ${n_processes}"

for file in $(find files/ -type f); do
    while [[ $(jobs -r | wc -l) -gt ${n_processes} ]]; do
       :
    done
    bash worker.sh "${file}" &
    echo "process pid: $! finished"
done

wait
```

It is not really a pool of processes but it avoids having a lot of processes at the same time alive, number maximum of processes alive at the same time is given by `n_processes`.

Execute `bash runner.sh`.

Comment: Any idea how to get this done? `/!\ 1000 processes is a lot it is better to create a pool of processes`

Comment: Ur idea of limit the processes is very good :) I'll give it a try!

Comment: I get the following syntax error: `syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: it is ok now ? I fixed that

Comment: Getting `line 6: ./worker.sh: Permission denied`. Any idea? :)

Comment: Now `No such file or directory`. Well, we got tons of `fileaa, fileab, fileac, filead, ...`. What shall I change?

Comment: I will detail the solution ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147531/discussion-between-glegoux-and-realksmc).

Comment: You might consider changing the `:` to `wait -n` since it will wait for at least one pending job to exit. This will avoid constantly running `jobs -r | wc -l` excessively.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this with **GNU Parallel**. Say you want 8 workers running at a time till all the processing is done:

```
parallel -j 8 --pipepart -a coords.txt --fifo bash worker.sh {}
```

where:

- -j8 means *"keep 8 jobs running at a time"*
- --pipepart means *"split the input file into parts"*
- -a coords.txt means *"this is the input file"*
- --fifo means *"create a temporary fifo to send the data to, and save its name in `{}` to pass to your worker script"*